# how to build xaml ui in Cocos2d for windows 8 metro application?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, cocos2d-iphone

we have been use cocos2d for windows 8 build metro game . so we want use xaml control UI in cocos2d ?
is there have soluction or suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

just try one night i have been fix this problem. you can click fllow link:

DirectX and XAML interop (Windows Store apps using C++ and DirectX) (Windows) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh825871.aspx

With the release of Windows 8, you can use XAML and Direct X together in your Windows Store app. The combination of XAML and DirectX lets you build flexible user interface frameworks that interop with your DirectX-rendered content, and is particularly useful for graphics-intensive apps. We explain the structure of a XAML app that uses DirectX, and identify the important types to use when building your XAML app to work with DirectX.

Answer (score 0):

soluction as fllow link:
http://www.cnblogs.com/chenkai/archive/2012/11/29/2794983.html

by chenkai

Answer (score 0):

Here's a template project in my github:

https://github.com/chanyuenpang/cocos2dxaml